# Some questions about $\ell$-adic monodromy

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology, monodromy, local-systems

I'm stucking on the proof of the Lemma 3.12 of [A p-adic analogue of Borel’s theorem](https://arxiv.org/abs/2310.06104).

Here $\mathcal A_{g,\mathrm K}$ is just a shimura variety defined over $\mathbb Z_p$, and full level $\ell$ structure means the $\ell$-part of $\mathrm K$ is contained in a principal congruence subgroup of $G(\mathbb Z_\ell)$. Knowing these there will be no problem for reading the proof.

I have the following questions:

1. Since the abelian scheme is pulled back to $G_m$, what does he mean by its reduction at $0$? Does it mean by extending this abelian scheme to $0$? But then, how?
2. In the second sentence of the second paragraph, what does "toric monodromy" mean?

Comment: Re. 1., the local ring of $A^1$ at 0 is a DVR, so an abelian scheme over its fraction field will extend canonically to a smooth separated group scheme - the Neron model - over the whole DVR. One can take the fiber of this at 0 - such a fiber is generally a disconnected group scheme whose connected component is a semiabelian variety. The authors seem to be claiming that this fiber is connected, but I could not see why this is true in their situation. Generally I could not follow the proof of Lemma 3.12 at all...

Comment: @Richard: Regarding (2), the authors are using the Neron-Ogg-Shafarevich criterion, which describes the reduction of an abelian scheme in terms of the local monodromy on it's $\ell$-adic Tate module. By "toric" I think they just mean "lies in a torus," i.e. since they in the tame setting, this just means that a generator of inertia goes to a matrix which is diagonalizable over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}_\ell}$.

Comment: @Satan'sMinion Thanks, but why is the connected component semiabelian?